# How to convert an array of arrays to an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What's the best way to convert a list of tuples to a dictionary in javascript?

One way is this:

```
var data = [['a',1], ['b',2],['c',3]]
var group_to_lengths = {} 

data.forEach(function(d) {
    group_to_lengths[d[0]] = d[1]; 
});
```

Is there a simpler or more idiomatic way of accomplishing the same thing? Perhaps like in python (`group_to_lengths = dict(data)`)?

Comment: The concept `dictionary` in JS does not exist. In JS there is objects and arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is more idiomatic for this case, like this

```
console.log(data.reduce(function(result, currentItem) {
    result[currentItem[0]] = currentItem[1];
    return result;
}, {}));
# { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

But, if you use a functional programming library, like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), then it would be just a one-liner with [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object), like this

```
console.log(_.object(data));
# { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```